# Can I plant a lychee in a pot?

Tags: fruit-trees, tree-care

I have a small garden, about 90 sq.m. I've grown some lychee plants from seed, and I'd love to plant them in my garden, but I don't want the tree to take over my whole yard. If I plant it in a large pot, will it still produce fruit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a forum dedicated to tropical fruit with at least one [discussion on lychees in containers](http://tropicalfruitforum.com/index.php?topic=12796.0). One contributor reports a little success with three ripe fruits and several others report success so the answer to the question is evidently yes, you can. However the thread makes interesting reading, noting that:

- the few good fruit result from many possible, so you should expect a lot of fruit drop
- the reporters are evidently located in Florida or Texas or similar areas with the associated heat and light year round,
- specific varieties are mentioned (e.g. Sweetheart),
- it requires a fairly large container which may be difficult to handle without specialist equipment,
- vigorous root pruning is involved
- the plant responds best in a container if propagated from air layering; the result is a tree with a fibrous root system which is easier to manage than if it is allowed to develop a more natural tap root which is less easily confined
- a mature lychee requires a lot of water
- the tree responds well to pruning, but this must be done immediately after harvest